# FluentNhibernate Max() Date with the rest of the values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent-nhibernate

Trying to use FluentNhibernate to query the following table using createCriteria.

```
IDCODE RATES DESCRIPTION EFFECTIVEDATE
1 SR 7 Standard Rated 2016-01-01 
2 SR 6 Standard Rated 2016-12-01 
3 TR 7 Transfer Rated 2016-01-01 
4 TR 6 Transfer Rated 2016-12-01
```

Select Max "EffectiveDate" where item are group by "Code"

know it can be done with HQL. But would like to try to use criteria if possible.

Query Result Wanted is

```
ID CODE RATES DESCRIPTION EFFECTIVEDATE
2 SR 6 Standard Rated 2016-12-01 
4 TR 6 Transfer Rated 2016-12-01
```

tried the following code.

```
DetachedCriteria maxDateQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<RatesModel>();
ProjectionList proj = Projections.ProjectionList();
proj.Add(Projections.Max("EFFECTIVEDATE"));
proj.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("CODE"));
maxDateQuery.SetProjection(proj);

var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<RatesModel>();
criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertiesIn(new String[] {"datetime", "connectionid"}, maxDateQuery))
.List<RatesModel>();
```

but its has the error:
'Subqueries' does not contain a definition for 'PropertiesIn'

so is there anyway to do this without using PropertiesIn?

Comment: Updated the question. thank you